# How to make the Qt Widgets from a window auto-expand its size if the window was resized by the user?

Tags: python, pyqt

I saw there is a solution if every widget is on a layout, but in my program I did't use any layouts. How can I make the QPushButtons and QLabels auto-resize if I resize the program's window?

Some code:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton, QMainWindow, QLabel
from PyQt5 import QtCore
import sys

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Resizable Widgets")
        self.setGeometry(500, 200, 300, 100)

        self.UiComponents()

        self.show()

    def UiComponents(self):
        label = QLabel("Label", self)
        label.setGeometry(0, 0, 300, 50)
        label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)

        button = QPushButton("Button", self)
        button.setGeometry(100, 50, 100, 40)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    sys.exit(App.exec_())
```

Comment: wait 10 minutes

Comment: [the minimal reproducible example](https://github.com/Kirusha05/ResizeWidgets/blob/master/resizeable.py)

Comment: I have not asked for a link, publish the MRE in your question as an edition. Read [ask]

Comment: @CugureanuChiril Surely you've already answered your own question: *use layouts*. Not using layouts is a very common newbie mistake. To begin with, it looks simpler, but very soon it will start to make many things much more complicated than they need to be. If you invest a little time now in learning how to use layouts properly, you will be greatly rewarded in the long-run.

Comment: Ok, but can someone show me the implementation of layouts in my code above

Comment: @CugureanuChiril Please learn how to do it yourself from this tutorial: [Layout management in PyQt5](http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt5/layout/). In fact, you may well benefit from working through the [whole PyQt5 tutorial](http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt5/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don’t use layouts, it might look like this:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPushButton, QMainWindow, QLabel
from PyQt5 import QtCore


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Resizable Widgets")
#        self.setGeometry(500, 200, 300, 100)

        self.w = 300
        self.h = 100
        self.resize(self.w, self.h)
        self.setMinimumSize(self.w/2, self.h/2)        
        self.widthFactor  = 1
        self.heightFactor = 1

        self.UiComponents()

    def UiComponents(self):
        self.label = QLabel("Label", self)
#        label.setGeometry(0, 0, 300, 50)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("font: {}pt Arial;".format(20*self.heightFactor))
        self.label.resize(self.w*self.widthFactor, self.h*0.25*self.heightFactor) 
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter) # | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)

        self.button = QPushButton("Button", self)
#        button.setGeometry(100, 50, 100, 40)
        self.button.resize(self.w*0.25*self.widthFactor, self.h*0.2*self.heightFactor)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self.widthFactor  = self.rect().width() / 300
        self.heightFactor = self.rect().height()/ 100        

        self.label.resize(self.w*self.widthFactor, self.h*0.25*self.heightFactor)
        self.label.move(self.rect().center() - self.label.rect().center() - QtCore.QPoint(0, self.h/4*self.heightFactor))
        self.label.setStyleSheet("font: {}pt Arial;".format(20*self.heightFactor))

        self.button.resize(self.w*0.25*self.widthFactor, self.h*0.2*self.heightFactor)
        self.button.move(self.rect().center() - self.button.rect().center() - QtCore.QPoint(0, -self.h*0.3*self.heightFactor))
        super(Window, self).resizeEvent(event)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(App.exec_())
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @S. Nick . This helps me understaning Python better. Thanks again bro!